# Having error while reinstalling mongodb in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to reinstall mongodb due to an error .
But when i run this

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

command its showing

```
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.pNFlfl1208/home:manuelschneid3r.asc.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 76F1A20FF987672F: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 14
gpg:       skipped new keys: 14
```

and i tried this command too

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg
```

still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by...

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org

sudo apt remove mongodb

sudo apt purge mongodb

sudo apt autoremove

sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb

sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb

sudo apt-get install gnupg

wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

sudo apt-get install libc6

sudo service mongod start

sudo service mongod status
```

This helped me with the issue